# Проблема с vk_api, python

Tags: vkontakte-api, бот

Бот не реагирует на сообщения в чате, в чём может быть проблема?

```
    from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api
import time
import random

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token='мой токен')
vk._auth_token()
vk.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 'айди группы')
while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.object.text.lower() == 'привет':
                    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': event.chat_id, 'message': 'Привет!', 'random_id': 0})
                elif event.object.text.lower() == 'бот лох':
                    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': event.chat_id, 'message': 'Пошёл ты!', 'random_id': 0})
                else:
                    vk.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': event.chat_id, 'message': 'Не понятно', 'random_id': 0})


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бот работает, проверьте данные в виде: токен, ID группы.
Также не забудьте настроить LongPoll в настройках группы и выдать боту в беседе права администратора.

Comment: Работает? Странно. Дело в том, что токен сделан, id группы тоже. Админ права выданы и longpoll включен. Может ли быть дело в том, что longpoll стоит на самой первой версии?

Comment: Да, версия не та стояла. Спасибо)